# Cannot access internet on android emulator?

Tags: android, emulation

I have been trying to run internet on the android emulator but with no success yet. I have tried most of the things i.e. trying to run with dns-server option argument, adding proxy configuration details in APN settings. It does make internet work on android emulator but only the browser is able to use it and not the applications. So have got the proxy removed but still am not able to use internet. In fact, after removing proxy even the browser is not able to connect to the internet.

Is having static IP associated with the system a necessity ? As, the system which I am using doesn't have a static IP?

Can anyone suggest what can be the issue?

Comment: if you have localhost in system Try typing 10.0.2.2 in emulator browser!

Comment: In my experience if the android browser is able to connect to the internet but your application is not then there is something wrong in your application, not with the emulator.

Comment: The browser only working with a proxy setting seems to suggest that your Internet service connection blocks direct connections and requires everyone to go through a proxy.  This may be supportable, but it will be rather painful to configure.

Comment: @Rarw - There is an issue with Android since long time that it doesn't provide support for Proxy globally. The browser is able to use the internet only when I configure Proxy settings in it otherwise not.

Comment: @ArunCThomas - Trying typing 10.0.2.2 in emulator browser gives Connection to the server timed out error dialog.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. There were some issues with IT policy on the system which was blocking android emulator from using the internet. Now, this has been resolved.

Comment: I think I have the same problem. Could you please explain what you did?

Comment: Please mention a meaningful compete answer when u post an answer even if it is for your own question. If not there is no use it it.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if this is obvious but do you have the right permission set in your app?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

In your `manifest.xml`?

Static IPs shouldn't be a requirement at all.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating new APN in the emulator.